# Why isn't my modal working in rails? Using a partial

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

The modal partial I have is saved in `shared/_task_modal` and is the following, the example on Bootstrap's documentation page:

```
<div id="task_modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using this js saved as `tasks/show.js.erb`.

```
$('.modal-body').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/task_modal'%>');
$('.modal-header').remove();
```

The link helper is as follows `<%= link_to task.title, "#taskModal", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>`

Why doesn't this work?

EDIT: I am also rendering it in Application layout: `<%= render "shared/task_modal" %>`

EDIT_2: Here is my Application.js. Is the load order wrong?

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Comment: We need more information to answer this. First of all, this isn't JS. Show us the actual JS, the project tree, etc.

Comment: @MichaelElliott My bad. Forgot to include it.

Comment: Try changing this `$('.modal-body').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/task_modal'%>");
`

Comment: Notice the double quotes

Comment: @DeepakMahakale This did not solve it either.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale please check edit_2

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to task.title, 'javascript:void(0)', "data-toggle"=> "modal", "data-target"=> "#task_modal"  %>
```

In `show.js.erb`

```
$('.modal-body').html("<%= j render 'shared/task_modal'%>");
```

Comment: Didn't work... This is the link i get in the address bar `http://localhost:3000/?data-target=%23taskModal&data-toggle=modal`

Comment: @waynard Try this:-
`<%= link_to task.title, 'javascript:void(0)', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#taskModal' %>`, please check the updated answer.

Comment: @waynard so far as i looking to your modal its has been giving `<div id="task_modal"..>` so at you link you should also use same id as `"data-target"=> "#task_modal"` also make sure in `show.js.erb` you are rendering in correct `div`

Comment: @waynard are you still facing this issue?feel free to accept/upvote answer for future so, if it helped you. please let me know for further guidance.

Comment: @waynard can you accept/upvote answer if it helped you?